# Detect text inside colored area in Pdf with Java

Tags: java, pdf, image-processing, pdfbox, text-processing

I have this project where I need to detect if a text is inside a red area (red rectangles) in a pdf invoices.

So **my first approach** was to convert the pdf to an image and get the pixels array of it , loop through the array , and check if the pixel is red , if there's red pixels and then black or some other color pixels followed by red pixels again that means that there's text inside a red area.

**Second approach** , get coordinates of each string, and somehow check if there's red pixels surrounding that area .

Any ideas , as to how to get this done ?

PS : in the first approach I was able to check if the pixels were red even if there was variations in red color , in the second one , I was able to get each string coordinates .

Comment: First of all, it's the text in question generated using text drawing instructions? (Can you copy&paste the text? )

Comment: yes you can copy&paste the text

Comment: Do you know where the red area is (in coordinates)? Or have you determine it for each invoice? In the latter case, how is that red area drawn? (Is it a rectangle path filled? A thick line? a bitmap image? Something else?)

Comment: I need to detect the red areas in each invoice , actually the red areas are drawn in a MS word "template" (as rectangles), that I convert to a png image then put it as an overlay over the pdf invoice

Comment: Then it would make more sense not to use this "template" at all, but to use the `ExtractTextByArea.java` example which uses the `PDFTextStripperByArea` class.

Comment: *"I need to detect the red areas in each invoice , actually the red areas are drawn in a MS word "template" (as rectangles), that I convert to a png image then put it as an overlay over the pdf invoice"* - I'm sorry but you lost me there. Why do you add that overlay? Can you expound? Probably sharing example files?

Comment: ok so to explain the whole process , we have invoices that need to follow certain measures like no text have to be in certain areas , so to determine those areas an expert created a template that have those areas drawn on it , it looks like this (https://imgur.com/a/t1sKmSr) . So we take that template and paste it over the invoices and see if there s some text in the red areas , if we find some text then the invoice is not accepted